# How to map through an object but separate into sections based on an object property?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

Practicing my react and javascript to build a football app

I can map each object out from the api one after the other in this component but I would like to insert an extra row in, or start a new div when it is a new round of fixtures

(see results[key].round in the object being mapped out)

that will contain "Regular Season - 38" or so on for each one.

I tried using a for loop but couldn't insert it in ResultsTable and have the map continue

this is my data

```
const results = {
    340: { round: "Regular Season - 34", awayTeam: "Arsenal", statusShort: 'FT',...etc}
    341: { round: "Regular Season - 34", awayTeam: "Liverpool", statusShort: 'FT',...etc}
    342: { round: "Regular Season - 34", awayTeam: "Man City", statusShort: 'FT',...etc}
    343: { round: "Regular Season - 35", awayTeam: "Arsenal", statusShort: 'FT',...etc}
}
```

this is how

```
 render(){

let results = Object.keys(this.props.league_fixtures)
    .filter( key => this.props.league_fixtures[key]
    .statusShort !== 'NS' )
    .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = this.props.league_fixtures[key], res), {} );

const ResultsTable = Object.keys(results).map((key) =>

 <tr key={results[key].fixture_id}>
    <td id={results[key].homeTeam_id}>{results[key].homeTeam}</td>
    <td onClick={ e => this.props.getFixture(results[key].fixture_id, results[key].league_id) }>{results[key].final_score}</td>
    <td id={results[key].awayTeam_id}>{results[key].awayTeam}</td>
 </tr>

)


return(
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th> Home </th>
     <th> x </th>
     <th> Away </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    {ResultsTable}
   </tbody>
  </table>
)
}
```

I want it to appear something like this

round 38

- fixture
- fixture
- fixture

round 37

- fixture
- fixture
- fixture

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to get what you want, IMO, using lodash `groupBy` function to convert your array to the object with all keys are `round`

I assume your data will look like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    awayTeam: "Arsenal",
    awayTeam_id: "2",
    elapsed: "0",
    event_date: "2019-04-15T19:00:00+00:00",
    event_timestamp: "1555354800",
    final_score: "0 - 1",
    firstHalfStart: "1555354800",
    fixture_id: "fixture_id1",
    goalsAwayTeam: "1",
    goalsHomeTeam: "0",
    halftime_score: "0-1",
    homeTeam: "Watford",
    homeTeam_id: "18",
    league_id: "2",
    penalty: "-",
    round: "Regular Season - 33",
    secondHalfStart: "1555358400",
    status: "Match Finished",
    statusShort: "FT"
  },
  {
    awayTeam: "Arsenal",
    awayTeam_id: "2",
    elapsed: "0",
    event_date: "2019-04-15T19:00:00+00:00",
    event_timestamp: "1555354800",
    final_score: "0 - 1",
    firstHalfStart: "1555354800",
    fixture_id: "fixture_id2",
    goalsAwayTeam: "1",
    goalsHomeTeam: "0",
    halftime_score: "0-1",
    homeTeam: "Watford",
    homeTeam_id: "18",
    league_id: "2",
    penalty: "-",
    round: "Regular Season - 34",
    secondHalfStart: "1555358400",
    status: "Match Finished",
    statusShort: "FT"
  },
  {
    awayTeam: "Arsenal",
    awayTeam_id: "2",
    elapsed: "0",
    event_date: "2019-04-15T19:00:00+00:00",
    event_timestamp: "1555354800",
    final_score: "0 - 1",
    firstHalfStart: "1555354800",
    fixture_id: "fixture_id3",
    goalsAwayTeam: "1",
    goalsHomeTeam: "0",
    halftime_score: "0-1",
    homeTeam: "Watford",
    homeTeam_id: "18",
    league_id: "2",
    penalty: "-",
    round: "Regular Season - 35",
    secondHalfStart: "1555358400",
    status: "Match Finished",
    statusShort: "FT"
  }
 ]
```

Using lodash `groupBy`

```
const groupedData = _.groupBy(data, 'round'); // _ is community standard for lodash object
```

You will get the object looks like this:

```
{
  'Regular Season - 33': [{...}, {...}] // Array objects with round is 33
  'Regular Season - 34': [{...}, {...}] // Array objects with round is 34
  'Regular Season - 35': [{...}, {...}] // Array objects with round is 35
}
```

Then you will iterate over the `groupedData` and `Object.keys(groupedData)` to render

```
const keys = Object.keys(groupedData);

return (
  <div>
    {keys.map(key => (
      <ul>
        <p>{key}</p>
        {groupedData[key].map(data => (
          <li>{data.fixture_id}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

My render function does not render table as you want but you got the idea.
Hope this help.

Comment: my data is more of a object of objects, see my edit, I tried converting it to an array but how do I bypass the key?

Comment: did you try my approach ?

Comment: ye but I made a spelling mistake, this is perfect, thank you